# Angular UI-Router. Dynamic Template URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic

I got a small situation I am creating a front end portion of an application using Angular and ui-router for the routing.

Te Database is holding the routes for the links. The url would look like (AdminMsgReview?init=1) which initiates the building of the frame.

I am trying to put that frame into a single page application (hence angular), I tried hard coding the url and i know it works and injects the frame into the view.

When i try to build it dynamically, I get the issue where the templateUrl is loading first before the resolve is finished getting the url.

This is the route.js

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: function(){
            return 'AdminMsgReview?init=1'
        }
    })

    .state('app', {
        url: '/app/:id/:fnid',
        resolve: {
            fnUrl: function(Toolbar) {
                    return Toolbar.getToolbar();
            }
        },
        controller: ['$rootScope', '$stateParams','fnUrl', function($rootScope, $stateParams, fnUrl){
            var mid = Number($stateParams.id) -1 ;
            var fnid = $stateParams.fnid;
            $rootScope.newUrl = fnUrl;
            $rootScope.url = JSON.stringify($rootScope.newUrl[mid].Function[fnid].URL);
            alert("Url should be = " + $rootScope.url);
        }],
        templateUrl: function($rootScope){
            console.log($rootScope.url);
            alert($rootScope.url);
            return $rootScope.url;
        }
    })
```

This is my factory for getting the data:

```
    var json = "rwd/resources/data/toolbar.json";
return{
    getToolbar : function(){
        return $q.all([
            $http.get(json)
        ]).then(function(results){
            var toolbar = [];
            angular.forEach(results, function(result){
                toolbar = result.data;
            });
            return toolbar.toolbar;
        });
    }
}
```